# Quand prononce-t-on une abréviation comme un acronyme ou un sigle ?

Tags: phonétique, abréviations, acronymes

Quel sont les règles qui gouvernent la prononciation d'un acronyme et un sigle ?

Voici quelques cas :

ATER (Attaché Temporaire d'Enseignement et de Recherche) : Pourquoi prononce-t-on chaque lettre et non comme un seul mot ?

Laser (light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation) : Pourquoi prononce-t-on comme un seul mot (et en plus pourquoi la prononciation est francisée vu que l'acronyme est anglais) ?

P.A.C.A., D.O.M., T.O.M., ONU, USA, en sont d'autres.

Comment: ATER est prononcé la plupart du temps en un seul mot. En règle générale, dès que c'est possible (prononçable et pas de confusion avec un autre mot) on le fait.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez > On peut je pense aussi ajouter la présence d'un H comme initiale. En effet j'imagine qui si on prononce HEC en citant toutes les lettre et pas "Heck" , c'est que dans ce dernier cas on n'entendrait pas le H

Comment: Tous les exemples que tu as donné se prononcent comme un mot (paca, dom, tom, onu, laser), sauf pour USA qu'on prononce en détachant les lettres (par contre je n'ai pas l'explication du pourquoi on utilise l'acronyme anglais et pas "EUA" pour états-unis d'Amérique)

Comment: @LaurentS. Bonne observation. En fait je crois que c'est plus général : on prononce en toutes lettres s'il n'y a pas de prononciation raisonnable en acronyme qui soit suffisamment proche de l'orthographe. Par exemple ENSI [ɛn.si], mais ENS [ə.ɛn.ɛs] parce que les consonnes finales de [əns] ne marchent pas en français et [ɑ̃] serait trop peu informatif.

Comment: @Flying_whale J'ai plus fréquemment entendu ONU prononcé en trois lettres qu'en un mot

Comment: Je pense qu'il n'y a pas de règle à proprement parler, mais que les prononciations sont consacrées par l'usage. Il y a de manière générale aussi, une tendance à limiter l'énoncé des mots à l'oral à deux syllabes, comme les diminutifs des prénoms de nos proches. (Lolo pour Laurent, Nico pour Nicolas) Certaines prononciations échappent à toute logique : le club de football toulousain, le TFC, se prononce "Téfécé". (et l'on se fait violemment reprendre si l'on dit "T.F.C.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je dirais que la prononciation joue sur plusieurs facteurs :

- La sonorité produite : cela sonne-t-il bien à l'oreille ? Est-ce prononçable ?

Par exemple, l'ASCii (norme de codage) est prononcé "*aski*" et pas "*aèscéihih*" essentiellement parce que ça sonne bien.

En revanche on prononce "*èsèncéèf*" (lettres séparées) et non "*sncf*" (un mot) pour SNCF parce que cela sonne terriblement mal.

- La fréquence d'utilisation : un sigle (prononciation des lettres) utilisé fréquemment dans un milieu va très souvent devenir un acronyme (mot) parfois au détriment de certaines lettres. Les personnes utilisant fréquemment un sigle estiment au bout d'un certains temps que la signification est connue de tous et qu'une prononciation plus rapide mais tronquée est permise.

Par exemple, le Centre Hospitalier Universitaire d'un campus sera nommé "*chu*" par les habitués et "*séachu*" par ceux qui ne le fréquente pas souvent.

- Quelle prononciation permet de conserver au mieux l'authenticité du mot tout en étant rapide : cela revient à la question sur le laser (et le radar aussi par exemple). Il est beaucoup plus facile (et rapide) de prononcer "*lazèr*" que "*èlaèseuhèr*" ou "*radar*" que "*èradéaèr*".

Précisions sur laser et radar : ces mots sont des sigles et acronymes anglais francisés car leurs équivalents n'existaient pas en français, et que la francisification de ces mots était facile.